# Conditionally replace select value from a mapping table

Tags: t-sql

I want to replace a value, in a `SELECT` statement, if the value matches a value in a lookup table. This is to handle a mapping from a child to a parent.

```
DECLARE @Mappings TABLE 
(
    IdKey INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
    ParentModule NVARCHAR(255) , 
    ChildModule NVARCHAR(255) 
)
```

This is populated with child modules and their parent module, there will be about 200 such mappings.

Then in my SELECT statement I want to use the ParentModule instead of the Child but if the child is not matched then use whatever value would have been selected.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        RTRIM(StudentId) ,
        ISNULL(( RTRIM(AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(AOSPeriod) ), '') AS Module 
FROM    Curriculum
```

The value I  want to compare to `ChildModule` is `(RTRIM(AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(AOSPeriod))`. So if that matches I want the select to return the @Mappings ParentModule, otherwise the value returned by the concatenation of AOSCode_AOSPeriod

The SELECT is used in an INSERT INTO statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        RTRIM(StudentId) ,
        ISNULL(Map.ParentModule,ISNULL((RTRIM(AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(AOSPeriod)), '')) AS Module 
FROM 
    Curriculum AS Cr 
    LEFT JOIN @Mappings AS Map ON 
        ((RTRIM(Cr.AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(Cr.AOSPeriod)) = Map.ChildModule;
```

You will join Expression `RTRIM(AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(AOSPeriod)` with `ChildModule`. If there is a match you will show `ParentModule`. Otherwise you will show `ISNULL(( RTRIM(AOSCode) + '_' + RTRIM(AOSPeriod) ), '')`.

Please take into account that I can not decide from your data if `ISNULL` have to be used in the expression in the join.